# Italian Ricevuta / Travelling outside of Schengen

Tags: air-travel, italy, visa-expiration, turkish-citizens

I am a Turkish citizen who studies in Italy. My permesso di soggiorno (residence permit) is expired and I made an application for renewal. I have my ricevuta from the post office. I left Italy 10 days ago to have a trip in Balkans. Currently , I am in Serbia. Can I fly back to Italy from here via direct fly? I read couple of times ricevuta can be used only for travelling to home country. (Turkey in my case) But Italian police’s web page doesnt specify something like that. It only says Italian residents can come back to Italy with their expired residence permit and ricevuta. I am thinking to go back to Italy with Ryanair. Is there a possibility for Ryanair to not recognize ricevuta and reject my boarding? Is there anyone who tried to travel from another extra-EU country to Italy with his/her ricevuta?
(I have seen another questions like this but they all want to travel to another Schengen country with their ricevuta.)

Comment: @Traveller the suggested duplicate concerns a trip to the Netherlands, which does not require passing the external border.  This trip, therefore, unlike the other, requires the traveler to clear Schengen passport controls.  Consequently, the airline's documentary requirements may well be different.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to fly directly to Italy from Serbia, or with a transfer in any non-Schengen country.  You would not be able to fly via another Schengen country.

The database that airlines use to check these requirements, TIMATIC, has this to say on the matter:

> **Visa Exemptions:**
>
> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Italy.
>
> **Additional Information:**
>
> Residents of Italy with an expired Residence Permit are permitted to re-enter Italy. They must also have a receipt issued by the Italian Post Office or Police Department proving that they have applied for the new residence permit in less than 60 days after the expiration date. They must return to Italy directly from outside the Schengen area.
>
> Valid visas in full, invalidated travel documents are accepted if accompanied by a new travel document.